# is there any way to call saveNote() in fragments when user clicks on backpressed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a save menu option in my fragment where I save the user's data, I also want to save the data onbackpressed in fragments?How can I achieve this ?

This is my saveMethod:

```
 public void saveNote() {
        title = edit_title.getText().toString().trim();
        text = txtnote2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (title.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (!text.isEmpty() || !title.isEmpty()) {
            long date = new Date().getTime(); // get current time;

            if (temp == null) {
                temp = new Note(title, text, date,activityName);
                dao.insertNote(temp); //inserts note record to db;
            } else {
                temp.setNoteTitle(title);
                temp.setNoteText(text);
                temp.setNoteDate(date);
                temp.setActivityName(activityName);
                dao.updateNote(temp);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // finish(); //return to main activity
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class));
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
```

I want to call this method onbackpressed in fragments 
How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell fragments when the back button has been pressed, first of all you need a base fragment which all of your other fragments inherit from. This base fragment implements the following:

```
 public interface OnBackPressed {
        void onBackPressed();
    }

    public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackPressed {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     // do what you want to save
       saveNote()}
    }
```

Now in your hosting Activity, call any implementations of the interface before any fragments are popped:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        saveData()
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void saveData(){
        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        for(Fragment f : fragments){
            if(f != null && f instanceof BaseFragment)
                ((BaseFragment)f).onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now but there's one issue. When I click on Onbackpress it is going back to my main activity but it takes few seconds to update my recycler view. When I remove super.onbackpressed from main activity then it is working fine but I can't exit my app. How to exit from application. ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
   /**
    * Could handle back press.
    * @return true if back press was handled
    */
   public boolean onBackPressed() {
       return false;
   }
}
```